# First day of the next year with rolling year in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-date-functions

I always need the 1st of the next year for a query in my Oracle. The date format from today's perspective should therefore look like this: `01-JAN-24`

However, this year should adjust automatically as soon as we count the year 2024.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to truncate `sysdate` to *year* (and get 1st of January this year) and then add 12 months.

To get last day of the next year, add 24 months (2 years) and subtract one day:

```
SQL> select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), 12) first_day,
  2         add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), 24) - 1 last_day
  3  from dual;

FIRST_DAY           LAST_DAY
------------------- -------------------
01.01.2024 00:00:00 31.12.2024 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `trunc(date)` is the function you need:

```sql
select 
    trunc(sysdate, 'y') current_year
from 
    dual t1
```

This returns 1st January of current year.

```sql
select 
    add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'y'), 12) shifted_year
from 
    dual t1
```

now we just add 12 months to it